# Convert a list of timestamped state columns into a time-indexed list for each state during that time, as told with Chutes and Ladders

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a game of Chutes and Ladders reduced to two tiles with no chutes and one ladder:

```
Start: [one] [two] :Finish
```

The ladder can take you from [one] to Finish, skipping tile [two].

When a game-piece (indexed by a number) starts the game, we create a timestamp for it when it enters a that tile.

Here's what a game with 4 game-pieces might look like:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
              one         two      Finish
1      2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-01-03
2      2014-01-02  2014-01-06  2014-01-08
3      2014-01-02         NaT  2014-01-05
4      2014-01-02  2014-01-07  2014-01-09
```

How can I convert it to a time-indexed DataFrame that counts how many pieces are on each tile during each time period? I want the resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
In [2]: new_df
Out[2]:
               one         two
2014-01-01       1           0
2014-01-02       3           1
2014-01-03       3           0
2014-01-04       3           0
2014-01-05       2           0
2014-01-06       1           1
2014-01-07       0           2
2014-01-08       0           1
2014-01-09       0           0
```

As I'm working with a (very large, 1MM+ row, dozen-column) DataFrame, making this computationally-thrifty would be splendid.

Thanks!

Comment: I may be missing something, but in your example output, why are there counts for 2014-01-03, 2014-01-04, 2014-01-08, etc?

Comment: @chrisb I think it's a running count (of the pieces currently in position one).

Comment: @AndyHayden Yup! Running count.

Comment: @gruen I think I've answered this, consider accepting if it's what you're looking for. Let me know if not performant enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think this problem becomes a little easier if we throw away the NaTs by backfilling (we can think of this that a piece is in two and then *immediately* in Finish):

```
In [11]: df = df.bfill(axis=1)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
         one        two     Finish
1 2014-01-01 2014-01-02 2014-01-03
2 2014-01-02 2014-01-06 2014-01-08
3 2014-01-02 2014-01-05 2014-01-05
4 2014-01-02 2014-01-07 2014-01-09
```

Now we can use `value_counts` and then `concat` to get the current pieces:

```
In [12]: ones = df['one'].value_counts()
         twos = df['two'].value_counts()
         finished = df['Finish'].value_counts()
```

We have to manually change the names as the don't propagate (yet...).

```
In [13]: ones.name, twos.name, finished.name = 'one', 'two', 'Finish'

In [14]: counts = pd.concat([ones, twos, finished], axis=1)

In [15]: counts
Out[15]:
            one  two  Finish
2014-01-01    1  NaN     NaN
2014-01-02    3    1     NaN
2014-01-03  NaN  NaN       1
2014-01-05  NaN  NaN       1
2014-01-06  NaN    1     NaN
2014-01-07  NaN    1     NaN
2014-01-08  NaN  NaN       1
2014-01-09  NaN  NaN       1

In [16]: total = counts.fillna(0).cumsum()

In [17]: total
Out[17]:
            one  two  Finish
2014-01-01    1    0       0
2014-01-02    4    1       0
2014-01-03    4    1       1
2014-01-05    4    2       2
2014-01-06    4    3       2
2014-01-07    4    4       2
2014-01-08    4    4       3
2014-01-09    4    4       4
```

Now you can get the desired DataFrame by looking at the column differences:

```
In [18]: pd.DataFrame({'one': total['one'] - total['two'],
                       'two': total['two'] - total['Finish']})
Out[18]:
            one  two
2014-01-01    1    0
2014-01-02    3    1
2014-01-03    3    0
2014-01-05    2    0
2014-01-06    1    1
2014-01-07    0    2
2014-01-08    0    1
2014-01-09    0    0
```

*There **may** be a much simpler/cheaper way to do this (if not, I think this would make a good feature request for pandas)...*

Comment: I think I've seen this kind of thing before, IMO there could be a convenience function for this.

Comment: This did the trick! In production data, there are a few NaTs in places that led to some weird aggregation issues. And, in practice, some game-pieces haven't finished the game yet, so had to make some adjustments there.

But, otherwise, this is fantastic and performs quickly enough! Thank you.